# SwiftUi - prevent update

Tags: swiftui

Basic question: how can I prevent a SwiftUI subview to redraw when the parent redraws?

I am experiencing performance issues on my project because so many nested views are constantly redrawn. Now, so of them are redrawn without anything being changed. To debug my problem, I even tried to simplify the problem to its core:

```swift
struct StupidView: View {

    init() {
        print("redraw")
    }

    var body: some View { 
        ZStack{}
    }
}
```

This empty view, of course, does not have any moving part that requires redrawing, but it gets redrawn every time its parent is redrawn.

I even tried to add a `.id(1)` to it with no results. Of course, my problem is with *complex* views whose useless redrawing slows down the app. How to **not** redraw parts of a view?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483313/12299030?

Comment: A direct subview of a re-rendered will *always* be re-inited (since there's no escaping the fact that you call `StupidView()`), but not always re-rendered. Your "redraw" actually prints on `init`, not redraw (when the `body` is called). Check @Asperi's comment for more detail about using `Equatable`.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a View has no meaning of rendering!

It does not rendered but got initialized try this down code, in SwiftUI initializing a View is pretty normal thing! A View could get Initializied 100 times but it will rendered if it needs! if your View has complex Content that SwiftUI get confused we can help SwiftUI in this way that make our View Equatable, then SwiftUI will understand when really need to rendered!

---

```
struct StupidView: View {

    init() {
        print("initializing!")
    }

    var body: some View { 
        print("rendering!")
        return ZStack{}
    }
}
```

Comment: print() in the view doesn't actually work. It would be useful to debug if a view is actually being redrawn or note. Any suggestion?

Comment: @pistacchio: I did not said it is going to fix something! It was a useful tool for you to monitor the rendering of your View! In your code you put print in initialising of View and you said get redrawn, my answer was trying to say, that is not true, the way of monitoring is as I answered in my question. you asked for any suggestion, I would say with amount of code you shared it is hard to know where is the issue, I suggest make a new question with the code make that issue happen, then we try work there, this current question is like  Basic question as you said! And I think I answered it.