# Swift - Prevent Entire View Render on Property Change

Tags: swiftui

TLDR is it possible to update a single published property in a ViewModel without causing the entire View that observes it to reload?

I have a Lottie animation on a subview, and am using Firebase Realtime Database to observe changes from a cloud object.  When using MVVM, anytime a property receives a change from Firebase the entire view re-loads, causing my animation to start again.  I need to maintain an observer of Firebase as other UI changes require a dynamic update, however when any one of them change I don't want to re-draw the entire view (and subsequently set off my animation).

I've tried both @EnvironmentObject and @StateObject (simplified version seen here), as well as using `!=` as a way of preventing an update to the local data from Firebase unless it's different.  I've read about `Equatable` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482098/swiftui-how-to-prevent-view-to-reload-whole-body)), however not sure if that's applicable here?  Is it possible to update individual properties and have the view respond specifically to them only?  Thanks!

```
// SomeViewModel() gets created in the App struct

// Main View
struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel

  var body: some View {
   LottieView(someViewModel: someViewModel)
  }
}

// Subview
struct LottieView: View {
  @StateObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel
    
  var body: some View {
    Lottie(name: someViewModel.lottieToShow, loopMode: .playOnce)
      .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
  }
}

// ViewModel
class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var lottieToShow: String = "lottie_city_animation"
  @Published var someOtherProperty: Bool = false

  private var isCity: Bool = false { didSet {
    updateLottie()
  }}

  private func updateLottie() {
     if isCity == true {
         self.lottieToShow = "lottie_city_animation"
     } else {
         self.lottieToShow = "lottie_park_animation"
     }
  }

  // Firebase

  private func readObject() {
     ref.child("users").child("01")
        .observe(.value) { snapshot in
           do {
              let firebaseObject = try snapshot.data(as: Object.self)
               if self.isCity != firebaseObject.isCity {
                    self.isCity = firebaseObject.isCity
               }
               if self.someOtherProperty != firebaseObject.someOtherProperty {
                    self.someOtherProperty = firebaseObject.someOtherProperty
               }
           } catch {
               print("Error reading value")
               }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you should be using
 `@ObservedObject var someViewModel: SomeViewModel` in your
 `ContentView` and `LottieView` instead of `@StateObject`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some pieces of code may have been oversimplified, `CallerViewModel` isn't used anywhere (unless it is presumably the same as `SomeViewModel`). `@Published` properties within an `ObservableObject` all trigger the same publisher to fire, namely the [`objectWillChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject/objectwillchange-2oa5v) publisher.

So that will be a dead end. In general be wary of `ObservableObject`s getting too big. You can refactor them apart, or pass in a `Publisher` to the view and use [`onReceive(_:perform:)`](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=Apple_API_Reference&docset_name=Apple%20API%20Reference&path=dash-apple-api://load?request_key=ls/documentation/widgetkit/accessorywidgetbackground/onreceive(_:perform:)%23&platform=apple&repo=Main&source=https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/accessorywidgetbackground/onreceive(_:perform:)) to respond to changes. Or pass certain data dependencies directly to a subview to try and keep changes targeted

Comment: Thanks for the comment (I have corrected the class name).  I see what you mean now by having the `ObservableObject` getting too big.  Since all of the properties come from the Firebase call, how would I refactor the ViewModel apart?

Comment: I ended up using `Equatable` [(Stack Overflow example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482098/swiftui-how-to-prevent-view-to-reload-whole-body) and setting a `var` in the view that gets checked.