# Temporarily prevent SwiftUI redraws

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any way to temporarily override SwiftUI's internal logic for when to redraw views?

Specifically, I have a rather complex view with a `ForEach { ... }` component. Everything works fine, but when the device is rotated, SwiftUI sees fit to re-render this entire view and all of its subviews 6 times throughout the animation of rotating to portrait/landscape mode, which causes the animation to hang.

None of the state variables actually change during that time, though the view is inside of a `GeometryReader` so `geography` will obviously update. Using an `EquatableView` won't help, because none of the state variables change.

I'm looking for a way to prevent all the redraws from happening, except for once after the device rotation is completed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI how to prevent view to reload whole body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482098/swiftui-how-to-prevent-view-to-reload-whole-body)

Comment: No, unfortunately. That method will only prevent it from redrawing the view if nothing has changed. My problem is that nothing has changed but SwiftUI redraws it anyway because it insists on being the sole mastermind of device rotation animations :(

Comment: SwiftUI can reload whenever it wants it is mentioned in several places in the documentation.

Comment: You should provide a [mre]. It seems likely there's something not being described here affecting things, but it's impossible to know. It also seems like something heavy might be done in a `View`'s `init`, but again, it's impossible to know