# Cannot disable SwiftUI View updates

Tags: swiftui, view, equality

My app has two modes:
A "run" mode executes very fast without any SwiftUI View update, and a "single step" mode where the user advances the app state manually and needs View updates at every step.
In the single step mode, SwiftUI updates my View as usual. For the run mode, I thought about to disable the automatic View update using a suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483313/1987726).
To test the approach, I wrote the following minimal project.
If I did understand the suggestion right, `CustomView` should not be updated, since the equality function returns always `true`.
But the View is updated and I don't understand why.

**EDIT:**
My app requires to switch between the run mode and the single step mode at run time. Thus, it is not possible to rebuild the app for the one or the other mode.

```
@Observable
final class Model {
    
    var counter = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }   
}

@main
struct ViewEquatableApp: App {
    
    let model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CustomView(model: model)
                .equatable()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View, Equatable {
    let model: Model
    
    static func == (lhs: CustomView, rhs: CustomView) -> Bool {
        // << return yes on view properties which identifies that the
        // view is equal and should not be refreshed (ie. `body` is not rebuilt)
        true // <- true should disable the View update
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(model: model)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Text("Counter: \(model.counter)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change the Observable not the View, why start the Timer in the first place?

Comment: My app requires to switch between the run mode and the single step mode at run time. Thus I cannot change the Observable without rebuilding. The timer is just there to show if the view is updated.

Comment: Timer can be substituted for anything else, whatever makes your app "run" shouldn't be running, your current approach doesn't really stop the "running" it just hides it. Any attempt to replace SwiftUI's automatic redraw is going to be buggy either now or the future, we aren't privy to that system.

Comment: I am sorry for this misunderstanding. The only thing I want to achieve is that during the run mode, the View is not updated because this would be much too slow. And I thought, the Equatable protocol for Views could be used for this case, as suggested in the ref provided. Why does it not work?

Comment: That is just a hack, nobody here can tell you why it doesn't work. Apple doesn't tell us everything about how SwiftUI works it is hidden behind a layer we can't see. Before iOS 17 it was heavily dependent on Equatable and Hashable, `@Observable` doesn't use either, it has its own mechanism we can't see, you can try `ObservableObject`s and hack a solution but it will likely break and be buggy, I posted a comment about "Demystify SwiftUI" on that post a while ago because there were so many questions on SO about this very issue, it hasn't worked reliably in iOS 16 either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My next attempt to achieve disabling SwiftUI View updates is the following.
I am learning SwiftUI, and I am sure this is not the best way to implement it. Any suggestion how to do it right is therefore highly welcome!
The approach sketched in the question is, as [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum) in his last comment pointed out, something that worked apparently with older SwiftUI versions but no longer when using the `@Observable` macro.
In any case this approach was much too complicated. There is a simpler solution that should work always.
A SwiftUI is normally re-drawn, when an observed property changes. This is normally controlled by a ViewModel, not by the DataModel itself.
I thus changed the code so that the `App` creates a `ViewModel` that is passed to the `ContentView`:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

`ContentView` accesses `viewModelCounter` of the passed `ViewModel`, and displays it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Counter: \(viewModel.viewModelCounter)")
    }
}
```

`ViewModel` is `@Observable`. It has a property `model`, the data model initialized here, and a property `viewModelCounter` that is displayed by the `ContentView`.

`Modal` has a property `mode` that determines if data changes in the model should be forwarded back to `ViewModel.viewModelCounter`. If so, changes to `ViewModel.viewModelCounter` would let `ContentView` to re-draw its contents. `Model` has also a property `modelCounter` that is incremented repeatedly by a timer, to simulate changing data. `Model` has also a reference back to its `ViewModel` to be able to change `viewModel.viewModelCounter` if requested.

```
class Model {
    var mode = Mode.singleStep
    var viewModel: ViewModel?
    var modelCounter = 0
    var changeDataTimer = Timer()
    
    func changeDataRepeatedly() {
        changeDataTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [self] _ in
            self.modelCounter += 1
            if mode == .singleStep {
                viewModel?.viewModelCounter = modelCounter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This test app works as required, but, as said before, it surely not the best solution.

Comment: Look decent, I would likely abstract  some more something like subscribe and unsubscribe to changes but this goes along the same lines to what I was mentioning in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Apple's new `@Observable` macro in your class, which automatically handles view updates wherever this class is used. As a result, every variable that is used in the body from that class is considered like `@Published` and the `model` in `CustomView` functions similar to `@ObservedObject` updating your view internally, while the `Equatable` protocol typically prevents unnecessary view updates triggered externally (e.g. by a parent view).

In your case, it would be more appropriate to use the conventional `ObservableObject` protocol for your class, marking properties with `@Published`. You can then use the `@ObservedObject` wrapper in any view where you want updates. Also, you don't need to implement `Equatable` protocol.

```
final class Model: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var counter = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ViewEquatableApp: App {
    
    let model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            CustomView(model: model)
                
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    let model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        ContentView(model: model)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Text("Counter: \(model.counter)")
    }
}
```

In this way only `ContentView` updates, remove `@ObservedObject` in it if you don't want it to update

Comment: Removing `@ObservedObject` requires to newly build the app. My app however requires to switch between the run mode and the single step mode at run time. I am sorry that I did not make this clear in my question. For this reason I think I still need the equatable views.

Comment: There is some truth to this "As a result, every variable within that class is considered as @Published" but that's not _why_ the view is being updated in this case. It's being updated because `model.counter` is being used in the `body` of the view and that's what prompts the update. If that property is _not_ used in the `body` it won't update on changes to `counter`

Answer (score 0):

The view in the original question is being updated because you have a reference to the `model.counter` in your `body` var. If you want to ignore this everywhere, you can mark the variable you do *not* want to update on like so `@Observable` class property with `@ObservationIgnored` like so

```
@Observable
final class Model {
    
    @ObservationIgnored var counter = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }   
}
```

If you just want *a specific* view to ignore that, then overriding the `==` to only be true if the properties you want to observe are equal as shown in your example will work for `ContentView`, but not for your `CustomView` as it does not appear to override the Observation macro designation to monitor for changes even though is may work for `@ObservableObject`s as mentioned in the answer by Loren Ipsum

In your original example however, `ContentView` should not be updating, you can verify this by checking to see if the `Self._printChanges()` is updated in the console

```
var body: some View {
    let _ = Self._printChanges()
    ContentView(model: model)
}
```