# How to set text position for all screen sizes in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on a measurements app, and I would like to set measurements in the object, looking at the image.

[image: demo]

That screenshot from iPhone 14 pro max, but when I run the app in iPhone 14 pro, the view is very bad. How can I solve that issue?

My code:

```swift
ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        Image("test3")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width * 1)
            .padding()
        
        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            
            Text(Joint.formatted())
                .position(x: geo.size.width - 383, y: geo.size.height - 350)
            
            Text(W1.formatted())
                .position(x: geo.size.width - 405, y: geo.size.height - 350)
            
            Text(L1.formatted())
                .position(x: geo.size.width - 382, y: geo.size.height - 350)
            
            Text(W2.formatted())
                .position(x: geo.size.width - 365, y: geo.size.height - 350)
            
            Text(L2.formatted())
                .position(x: geo.size.width - 350, y: geo.size.height - 350)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest, you put the `GeometryReader` in an overlay over the image. This way, the `GeometryReader` is measuring the exact size of the image and does not include empty screen space or padding. Then you can then use relative meausrements to set the label positions. A `ZStack` can be used to contain the labels.

Like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Image("test3")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .overlay {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                let w = geo.size.width
                let h = geo.size.height
                ZStack {

                    Text(Joint.formatted())
                        .position(x: w * 0.05, y: h * 0.48)

                    Text(W1.formatted())
                        .position(x: w * 0.19, y: h * 0.48)

                    Text(L1.formatted())
                        .position(x: w * 0.41, y: h * 0.48)

                    Text(W2.formatted())
                        .position(x: w * 0.63, y: h * 0.48)

                    Text(L2.formatted())
                        .position(x: w * 0.84, y: h * 0.48)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
}
```