# How to "fix" a button on a specific position in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uibutton

I have a TV remote image asset complete with buttons where I lay invisible buttons on top of it to make it functional. The problem is, since the invisible buttons need to be over their respective graphic counterparts like pause, play etc. the buttons should be fixed at a certain position, regardless of the device size. I've tried GeometryReader, RemoteGeo, even some UIKit modification that ChatGPT suggested to no avail. Can someone be kind enough to help me out?

Sample buttons are below:

```swift
private func iphonePortraitButtons() -> some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                // Design for Portrait Mode
                
                ////////////////DVD PAUSE BUTTON////////////////
                Button(action: { let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                    generator.impactOccurred()
                    isDVDLogoPaused.toggle() }) {
                        Rectangle().opacity(1)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    .frame(width: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.15,
                           height: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.08)
                    .position(x: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.158,
                              y: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.13)
                
                ////////////////INFO BUTTON////////////////
                Button(action: { let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                    generator.impactOccurred()
                    showFloatingIsland.toggle() }) {
                        Rectangle().opacity(1)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    .frame(width: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.16,
                           height: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.05)
                    .position(x: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.675,
                              y: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.077)
                
                //////////////////DIGITAL CLOCK BUTTON////////////////
                Button(action: { let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
                    generator.impactOccurred()
                    showDigitalClock.toggle() }) {
                        Rectangle().opacity(1)
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    .frame(width: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.16,
                           height: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.031)
                    .position(x: remoteGeo.size.width * 0.310,
                              y: remoteGeo.size.height * 0.095)
          
                }
               }
              }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to implement a concept similar to Android's floating-action button. There are many tutorials on the internet that guide you through how to do that. For example, the very first link from my googling: https://sarunw.com/posts/floating-action-button-in-swiftui/.

Comment: You probably want to have a `GeometryReader` at the top level, then give the buttons relative positions based on its size. These posts show how it's done: [How to set text position for all screen sizes in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77363948/20386264), [Automatically aligning the content shape of a button with the opaque parts of its image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77355868/20386264).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically aligning the content shape of a button with the opaque parts of its image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355868/automatically-aligning-the-content-shape-of-a-button-with-the-opaque-parts-of-it)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem may be that the buttons are contained in a `VStack`. Try removing the `VStack`, so that the buttons are held by the `ZStack` instead. Then put a `GeometryReader` around the `ZStack` to give you the size. This whole view can then be applied as an overlay to the TV image.

Here is an adaption of your example to show it working. The sizes that you were setting on some of the buttons were very small, I increased them a bit.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private func buttonIcon(systemName: String) -> some View {
        Image(systemName: systemName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundStyle(Color(white: 0.2, opacity: 0.2))
    }
    
    private func iphonePortraitButtons() -> some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let w = proxy.size.width
            let h = proxy.size.height
            ZStack {
                
                Button {
                    print("pause")
                } label: {
                    buttonIcon(systemName: "pause.rectangle.fill")
                        .frame(width: w * 0.16, height: h * 0.16)
                        .position(x: w * 0.158, y: h * 0.13)
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("info")
                } label: {
                    buttonIcon(systemName: "info.square.fill")
                        .frame(width: w * 0.16, height: h * 0.16)
                        .position(x: w * 0.675, y: h * 0.077)
                }
                
                Button {
                    print("clock")
                } label: {
                    buttonIcon(systemName: "clock.fill")
                        .frame(width: w * 0.16, height: h * 0.16)
                        .position(x: w * 0.310, y: h * 0.095)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "tortoise")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundStyle(.orange)
            .background(.blue.opacity(0.1))
            .overlay {
                iphonePortraitButtons()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]